# How to use Python's scipy.signal.remez output for scipy.signal.lfilter?

Tags: python, scipy, digital-filter

I am creating a bandpass filter in python. I calculated the transfer function coefficients using signal.remez, and the frequency response looks just how I want it to. However, signal.remez returns a single 1D array of coefficients. I was expecting two arrays, a set each for the numerator and denominator of the transfer function.

How do I use the output of the python remez algorithm in signal.lfilter?

Code Snippet:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter, remez

def Rfilter(data, samplerate):
    g           = samplerate/2.
    f           = g/62.5
    e           = f*0.875
    d           = e*(3./7.)
    c           = d*(4./15.)
    coeff           = remez(400, [0, c, d, e, f, g], [0, 1, 0], Hz=samplerate, maxiter=100)
    return coeff


infile      = 'data.csv'
data        = open(infile, 'r')
data        = data.readlines()
X           = []
V           = []


for line in data:
    line        = line.strip().split(',')
    X.append(float(line[0]))
    V.append(float(line[1]))


timestep    = X[1] - X[0]
samplerate  = 1/timestep

#Here is the array of coefficients that remez returns. 
coeff       = Rfilter(V, samplerate)

#From coeff, need to generate a and b, the numerator and denomenator coefficients
#FV             = lfilter(a, b, V)
```

Comment: this question belongs rather to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since the previous version of my question was too long, I'll move the signal processing portion to the suggested stack exchange. I hope the edited version is sufficiently narrowed.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.remez.html

Comment: The revision is better; including a code sample of what you've tried will help it much more

Comment: @STW Code sample is added. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @m.wasowski I've checked the documentation. Remez returns an array that is "The output of the digital filter," a statement that I find somewhat frustrating. How do I use this array? It doesn't appear to be my filtered data. It must then be the coefficients to the transfer function. However, a transfer function requires to sets of coefficients. Those for the numerator and those for the denominator.  If I knew how to extract the coefficients from this array, I could then pass them to signal.lfilter.

Comment: np, and welcome to SO.  It's worth checking out the FAQ since this isn't quite your typical Q&A site, but you'll get the hang of it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `data = (72, [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5], [0, 1, 0]); signal.lfilter(signal.remez(*data), [1], data[1])` (please take into account, that I know next to nothing about dsp, it is just from reading docs and some common sense...)

Comment: @m.wasowski I think you may be right, but I am hoping for a more concrete answer.

Comment: @m.wasowski After trying other possible combinations, your method is certainly looking like the correct one. Thank for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an old question, but with over 1000 views, perhaps there are still people showing up here with similar questions.

[`scipy.signal.remez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.remez.html) computes the coefficients of a [*finite impulse response*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) (FIR) filter.  The output is just one set of coefficients.  You say you expected two sets of coefficients, which means you expected `remez` to design an [*infinite impulse response*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) (IIR) filter, but `remez` does not do that.

You can apply the filter with a convolution function such as `numpy.convolve` or [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).  You can also use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).  `lfilter` accepts the coefficients of an IIR filter.  The first two arguments of `lfilter`, `b` and `a`, are the coefficients of the numerator and denominator of the IIR filter.  You can pass an FIR filter to `lfilter` by setting `b` to the coefficients returned by `remez`, and setting `a=1`.  (In other words, an "IIR" filter with a trivial denominator is, in fact, an FIR filter.)